# MySQL in XAMPP stops unexpectedly whenever an activity is created in MOODLE

Tags: php, database, mysqli, xampp, moodle

First of all we created a moodle site on our local machine. Afterwards we integrated our work using TFS (Team Foundation Server). Now we changed the ibdata1 file in our database which includes the change of all people and took the latest version of the site from TFS. But now whenever any activity or resource is being created in MOODLE site, mysql stops unexpectedly and says DATABASE READ AND WRITE ERROR; while login takes place effectively and reads the username and password from database. The error message shows that your database must be corrupted or you may not have the priveleges or block port or shutdown by another method. While log shows database "you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
doesn't support." and sometimes "The InnoDB memory heap is disabled". Please help.

Comment: Did you create a new database, run the Moodle install (including the install code for your custom modules) and then restore courses by backup (as I recommended in response to your last question about this) or did you try to directly merge together the databases from all the different developers?

Comment: No I tried directly. Will this not work? Because for login and other thing it is working properly but not while creating a new activity. Because whatever you mentioned in my previous question I had to start from base which would have taken a lot of time.

Comment: Error: page 2096 log sequence number 64298408
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 40312973.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.                      **This is the main error log shown in xampp**

Comment: Directly merging databases is going to produce inconsistencies - for example course module '10' one one site might be a forum in course '3', on another site it might be a quiz is course '2'. Without using backup + restore, you can't get the data to be consistent.

Comment: **Thank you** 
Everything is working fine now... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you copied the database frm files rather than doing a data dump? This won't work. You need to do a database dump and restore.

On the original server either use phpmyadmin or mysqldump. Phpmyadmin should be already installed by xammp

If the server is your local machine, you can access phpmyadmin via

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Then go to database name, click the export tab and click go. This will download an sql file.

Then on the destination server, do the reverse. Go to phpmyadmim, you will need to create a blank database, then click the import tab and select the sql file.

Also copy the moodle data folder, this is a straight forward copy.

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Moodle_migration

Don't try to merge 3 databases, the id's will be out of sync and the data will be completely useless.

If the code from the other developers has been written correctly, they will have install.xml files and possibly upgrade.php or install.php files to make any structure changes to the database.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Upgrade_API

Comment: **Thank you** 
Everything is working fine now... :-)